# How do I fix this error? Mongooseconnection error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run my application and it keeps giving me this error and this is from  a demo app from sitepoint. This is the details of the app
https://www.sitepoint.com/build-simple-beginner-app-node-bootstrap-mongodb/

The error:

```
     throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
        ^
    MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mo
    ngoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
        at new MongooseError (C:\Users\tychi\WebstormProjects\demo-node-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\mongooseError.js:
    10:11)
        at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\tychi\WebstormProjects\demo-node-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\conne
    ction.js:579:11)
        at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\tychi\WebstormProjects\demo-node-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:333:15)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tychi\WebstormProjects\demo-node-app\start.js:4:10)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

the code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.demoapp ,
    { useNewUrlParser: true },
    { useUnifiedTopology: true })


mongoose.connection
    .on('open', () => {
        console.log('Mongoose connection open');
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(`Connection error: ${err.message}`);
    });

require('./models/Registration');

const app = require('./app');

const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Express is running on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Comment: is your `process.env.demoapp` is `string`?

Comment: my .env file is DATABASE=mongodb://localhost:27017/<demoapp>

Comment: After looking to your tutorial share I found you need to write `DATABASE=mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds211709.mlab.com:11709/<dbname>?authSource=<dbname>`  and you you are accessing `demoapp` instead of  `DATABASE` so add `process.env.DATABASE`